# Letting a blank criteria equal all records

Tags: ms-access

I have a database reporting on staff quality reviews. There is a query which returns an average of passing results for all staff. I'd like to be able to limit this query *sometimes* to a particular unit based on if a unit is selected in a dropdown control. This would allow me to have just a single form that would report either all staff (if no unit is selected) or the data for the particular unit. (if it is) I tried an If statement in the criteria but I got lost pretty quickly. I was trying `IF «Expr» Forms![MainMenu]![btnManagersMenu].Form![txtADUnitPT] NOT IsNull THEN Unit = Forms![MainMenu]![btnManagersMenu].Form![txtADUnitPT] ELSE Unit = Null` Now I think I know that null cant really be equal to anything, but I thought I'd try to show what I tried with the hope that someone might be able to point me in the right direction.

Comment: `IS NOT NULL` not `Not IsNull`, also, it seems like you're using an `If... Then` statement in a place where it's not allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using a parameter query? You could either enter a unit or leave the parameter empty which would give you the total result. To get you started:

SELECT ***Data location Field Here***, [Enter Unit or Leave Blank for All] AS Expr1

FROM ***Data Location Field Here***

WHERE  ***Data Location Field Here***=[Enter Unit or Leave Blank for All] OR ***Data Location Field Here***=[Enter Unit or Leave Blank for All]) Is Null))

Comment: Thanks! I figured it was something simple but I'm a total noob.